# iAds: Removing or adding?

Tags: iphone, ios4

Apple requires you to make your app work nicely, whether iAds are available or not, which makes perfect sense. What I'm wondering about is the transition between those two states.

Should I create a view that has a space for an iAd and push it to the screen. If no iAds are available, I then have to remove the `ADBannerView` once the view is shown.

Or, should I create a view that has no space for an iAd in the first place and create such a space whenever an iAd finished loading?

Apple seems to use the first scenario. But I find it visually more appealing when the Ads slide in, once they are loaded rather than sliding out a failed ad. What do you think? Is there any reason not to go for the second scenario?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second approach seems reasonable and more pleasing. It comes with a cost on the implementation / design side. If this doesn't matter, go for it.